# Remove custom code workflow programmatically

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

For a variety of reasons too convoluted to explain here, I find myself in a position where I need to be able to remove custom code workflows, while leaving the solution there.

I essentially have the same code as the plugin registration tool

Namely

```
service.Delete("plugintype", new Guid(info));
```

where info is the workflow id [running on a foreach loop but that's beside the point]

However, while the tool removes the workflows without any issues, my code complains about dependencies.

EM:

Additional information: The PluginType(a0b2dcf7-cf2a-111e-7da9-003021880a42) component cannot be deleted because it is referenced by 1 other components. For a list of referenced components, use the RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest.

which I duly did

```
RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest req = new RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest();
req.ComponentType = 90; //plugintype
req.ObjectId = new Guid(info);
RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse resp = (RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse)OrgService.Execute(req);
```

This retrieves an optionvalueset, but there is little I can do with it as I cannot remove it from the solution as the solution is managed.

The only difference I can see is the way the OrganizationServiceProxy gets instantiated.  The plugin registration tool includes a way to refresh the securitytoken, but as far as I can tell it's not doing much (I've stepped through the code, but it's possible I missed something)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it is an OptionSetValue that is the dependency?  It's much easier to use GUI to determine what the dependencies are.  Fire up your solution in CRM 2011, click 'plug-in assemblies', select the relevant assembly then go through each custom workflow/plugin item and click 'Show Dependences'.

In my case I had another workflow (created within CRM) that was referencing a custom workflow preventing removal of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to remove components from a Managed solution... Are you the author of the solution originally?

As an aside, does your workflow fire on change of the OptionSet that is showing as a dependency?

Comment: I know I can't remove components from a managed solution, but it is possible to remove them from the system, which is what I'm doing. It's just not working for Workflows but it works for plug-ins

Comment: And my other question was "does your workflow fire on change of the OptionSet that is showing as a dependency?"

Comment: I've not checked, I did not write the workflows, just some of the plug-ins

Comment: Are you sure that it is an OptionSetValue that is the dependency?  I faced the same issue as you.  Looking within the RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse (in resp.Results.First().Value as EntityCollection).Entities[0].FormattedValues) shows that the retrieve dependency request returns 'dependentcomponenttype' (e.g. workflow) and 'dependencytype' (published/unpublished status) stored within OptionSetValues.  Looking in the FormattedValues will show you what the true dependency might be.